# Turn a sentence into a dictionary

Tags: code-golf, string

For this challenge, you will be given a long string as an input. With this string, you must create a dictionary.

### Details:

This dictionary will contain all the words from the string - a word being any sequence of letters surrounded by non-letter characters (ASCII). Letter case of the entries of the dictionary should always be consistent (i.e. all lower case or all upper case, or only the first letter of each word is capitalised). The dictionary can be a list, array, or any other type so long as the words are distinct from each other. Finally, as this is a dictionary, the words must be in alphabetical order, and there may not be any duplicates.

You can assume no contractions will be used (the input will never contain `it's`, `there's`, etc.), and that there will always be at least one word

### Some examples:

```
"this is an eXaMpLe of an Input" -> ["an","example","input","is","of","this"]
"Here is another example of an input, this time with Punctuation!" -> ["an","another","example","here","input","is","of","punctuation","this","time","with"]
"290(&79832aAa(*& *79 --=BBBb)bbBb ( x )*d -cxaAa_" -> ["aaa","bbbb","cxaaa","d","x"]
```

### Scoring

Shortest code wins

Comment: Are we guaranteed the input will contain at least one word?

Comment: May we include the empty word at the start of our dictionary?

Comment: yes, it's guaranteed at least one word, I'll update it

Comment: Note that in standard computer-science terminology, a "dictionary" data structure is a map: each entry has associated storage of some type beyond the mere fact that it's present.  You're using the common English meaning, which is fine, but real dictionaries have definitions.  This is just a word-list.  Probably fine to leave the title and description as-is, but in programming terms the problem is to tokenize a string into an *ordered set* of words.

Comment: Could you answer @JonathanAllan's question as well, please? And, if we _can_ include it, must we do so consistently?

Comment: Should I lemmatize it or not?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm going to disallow the empty word at the start because the answers that are already posted follow this guideline. As for lemmatizing the dictionary, you don't have to (walked and walk should be different entries)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input contains non-letters, or is a single word without anything else a valid input?

Comment: I suggest a test case where a word is repeated twice ;)

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>57</s>  51 bytes

Returns a Set of words in lower case.

NB: In JS, the elements of a Set are guaranteed to appear in insertion order. In this case, this  is the order defined in the sorted array the Set is built from.

```javascript
s=>new Set(s.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+/g).sort())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBS8NAEIXv/opxD2U3NonUQ@0hgvGiUEHwIpQgk3TSRNrdkN2Y4J@P0zSlqD247M7bgdn3PvYDP9FmdVk5X5s19XnU2@hOUwuv5KQNnFmaluoHtCRVsEOXFTJcof@VXIUbFVhTO6lUnxltzZaCrdnIXApXlBZ4owZ6w@dqSWDyffekq8YJpeAfKwxhJVCLqaAOd9WW@FYO71ktF5Nz2UeJ5OIXwCPVdAAwrqAaRoeRYnCZwkDpyh1BW7oCXhqduQZdafTlgHgCGG1@oHB/nqg6@Rz5WDiGZR/0l3a2uJaT@eL2Zob3KL0JePMF@H4Ux3Gq0jROQUIHyluDn3U88n7uBw@0iJyS8mLh2aFd8@lE0n8D)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 33 bytes

```ruby
p$_.upcase.scan(/[A-Z]+/).sort|[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBC4IwHMXvfYp/EKLWNOxgHjroqaCgYyQi21o40G24jQz67C0tgnf58X7v9ZY8nVOLOrKKYs0iTbHw4zJH12oZB5GWvXmVlXOm4RrGYAHsgk/qyEDeJzoIZc1sz3r2q6VpWA9swJ1q/w6fnBV8PwzvGDy4aeBsBTUWGy7FfJZka99Ls@0mwTn2Qw/CNAOEdkVRkICQgoAPAwThDRAdRqV@SzUttUOi/QA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
èñ≤!á~¬
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8aa4f321a07eaa&i=%22this+is+an+eXaMpLe+of+an+Input%22%0A%22Here+is+another+example+of+an+input,+this+time+with+Punctuation%21%22%0A%22290%28%2679832aAa%28*%26+*79+--%3DBBBb%29bbBb+%28+x+%29*d+-cxaAa_%22&a=1&m=2)

The output dictionary is produced as a space separated word list.

Comment: It would be amazing if Stax's source compression also does Huffman coding.

Comment: It doesn't now, but that's an interesting idea...

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
S{c:r0Q"[^a-z]"d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P7g62arIIFApOi5RtypWKeX/fyUjSwMNNXNLC2OjRMdEDS01BS1zSwVdXVsnJ6ckzaQkpyQFDYUKBU2tFAXd5AqgknglAA)

```
S{c:r0Q"[^a-z]"d   Implicit: Q=input(), d=" "
    r0Q            Convert input to lowercase
   :   "[^a-z]"d   Regex replace non-alphas with a space
  c                Split on spaces
 {                 Deduplicate
S                  Sort, implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 19 bytes

thanks to @FryAmTheEggman and @Neil for -5 bytes!

```
T`Llp`ll¶
D`
G`.
O`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyTBJ6cgISfn0DYulwQu9wQ9Lv@E//@NLA001MwtLYyNEh0TNbTUFLTMLRV0dW2dnJySNJOSnJIUNBQqFDS1UhR0kyuASuIB)

`` T`Llp`ll¶ `` convert the letters to lowercase and everything else to newlines.

`` D` `` deduplicates lines.

`` G`. `` removes empty lines.

`` O` `` sorts the lines.

Answer (score 3):

## gawk -F[^a-zA-Z]+, 93 bytes

```
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!=""){a[tolower($i)]=1}}n=asorti(a,b);for(j=1;j<=n;j++){print b[j]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCoMwFIXhV7lKB4M6OMcMXUqn0rliIZaI12oS4hVLJa/eNE4Hfs4nt3cIe29chqLiWIvbhWOesx377ISJSFO2y4bMZDblYmGtqLzXQi7GEWay6Bg/9Bj1WAvNxwNbh5qga8bW@xCuyinABaQ2NCgH6iNnOykwfUyA2q5UAA3xQTgr2JAGuK/6RaskNDr5GXvsEspL85Tl91w@2vwP)

Works for GNU AWK, not regular AWK, due to the use of the `asorti` function.

The input is split on anything which isn't a letter, leaving the words in `$1`, `$2`, etc. We iterate over the numbered variables, and, if they aren't equal to the empty string<sup>†</sup>, we put them, lowercased, into an associative array `a` as an index. Once done, we sort the indices of the array `a` and put the result into an array `b`. Finally, we print the elements of `b`, in order.

<sup>†</sup>We need the test for an empty string, because if the input string ends with a non-letter, the last numbered variable will be an empty string.

Comment: This trims off some bytes... `{for(;i<NF;)$++i?a[tolower($i)]=1:0;for(;j<asorti(a,b);)print b[++j]}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Two bytes can be saved if we can include the empty string in the "dictionary". Will update explanation upon confirmation.

```
v q\L f â n
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=diBxXEwgZiDiIG4&input=WwoidGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlWGFNcExlIG9mIGFuIElucHV0IiAKIkhlcmUgaXMgYW5vdGhlciBleGFtcGxlIG9mIGFuIGlucHV0LCB0aGlzIHRpbWUgd2l0aCBQdW5jdHVhdGlvbiEiCiIyOTAoJjc5ODMyYUFhKComICo3OSAtLT1CQkJiKWJiQmIgKCB4ICkqZCAtY3hhQWFfIgpdLW1S) - Includes all test cases

```
v f"%a+" â n     :Implicit input of string
v                :Lowercase
  f              :Match
   "%a+"         :  RegEx /[a-z]/g
         â       :Deduplicate
           n     :Sort
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>89</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>61</s></sup> 60 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [640KB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84624/640kb)!!!

```python
lambda s:sorted({*re.findall("[a-z]+",s.lower())})
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFta4MwEMff@yluedEmTsvWDvoAHayvNthgLwdWRqyRBmwMMVJX8bO782nrYEFzufN35/9y@sseM7Voku2@SfkpijnkmzwzVsS0co2YJVLFPE0pCbh/CW@Jl8/S7CwMZaxmjjxpZMGIxorc5rAF6gAuYo8yB3y4AvHB3/SrgCxpvRelC0u8nnoWRvRUZo/CgCj5SacjKlvUg66UlScBZ2mP8F6ogy24lZm6GevM13d0slyvFnP@xKk7AXe5Bt/f7na7iEXRLgIKJTA3Bv9QIvKJicwRpRYHbPRHdUC4Ih4ZVOBJ9mKJzHHLEtxaMST0rvFB/J9E9P/P17/qx2posDk0bXtXtTnHWIQLDaru3BjfsmWYY1B2UEz3xXx5v5p6MBwfpqGTZAbaeXjQt4g3CRepaTejMShitul@1U4t6b6xztdGKksTUrWhGvxHqPIaKhMguB2Sw5qw5hs)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
⇩`[a-z]+`$ẎUs
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%87%A9%60%5Ba-z%5D%2B%60%24%E1%BA%8EUs&inputs=%60%22290%28%2679832aAa%28*%26%20*79%20--%3DBBBb%29bbBb%20%28%20x%20%29*d%20-cxaAa_%22%20-%3E%20%5B%22aaa%22%2C%22bbbb%22%2C%22cxaaa%22%2C%22d%22%2C%22x%22%5D%60&header=&footer=)

-3 thanks to Razetime.

+1 because I forgot to sort it.

Comment: 14: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%87%A9%60%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5D%60%E1%B9%A1'&inputs=%60uaeg%20hosei%20gheisu%20hveiosfj%20k%60&header=&footer=)

Comment: 12: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%87%A9%60%5Ba-z%5D%2B%60%24%E1%BA%8EU&inputs=%60uaeg%20hosei%20gheisu%20hveiosfj%20k%60&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Razetime Nice, I forgot I could lowercase it first!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't seem to work for testcase #3. Edit: It also doesn't seem to sort the list at any point.

Comment: @Underslash Oops, forgot to sort the list. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## perl -Mfeature=say -MList::Util=uniq -n, 31 bytes

```
say for sort@e=uniq lc=~/\pL+/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BCsIwEETvfsV6kVoNiiJaoaA9KVTwIngQJK1bG6hJTDZYL366sVWEuczO22VHo6lm3lv@hEIZsMrQCmMnxR2qPH6NTjodjK7eUyksNOIS8Mh3OkVQReu2UjvqbNDgL1ZUogGs@U1Xf0a0zBC@N0jcEB6CStg7mZPjJJTsdibROOjNo8V0wtc8CHsQziNgLE6SJOtnWZJBADX0wwuwvG6Q81vpdtN6tkuFpeXyQKL6Pu6ZbIYFcnIG46bZBw)

Lowercases the input string (read from `STDIN`), extracts sequences of letters, removes duplicates, sorts and prints them.

Comment: Nice! I'm sure there's a way to overuse `-F` which I might play with later! For this, you can save two bytes removing `@e=` by swapping `sort` and `uniq`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BasMwEETv@YrJJThORUpKcB3woT414EAuhR4KQXbXscCRVGlF3Es/vYrdEpjL7Lxddiy5fhujl99ojUPQ6gveOEbfFD/rD1ut1ucYuVMeo6QGvcuDrQimndxe28CzV3L0HxvuyIEGebH9nVET84C/G6wuhKviDsegGw6SldHz2SZ/TBZZ/vy0kS8ySRdIsxxCFGVZ1su6LmskGLBMPyGaYUROv8ZOmz6KQ6U873ZvrPpi@j4KPQ5bkhwcFWOvGw "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 29 bytes

```
{sort unique m:g/<:L>+/».lc}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczfioJAHMXxVzlB@K@saGFLN4O8Kijocu9kdH@uAzpj4wwZ0ZN114u5uRGcmwMfvjWp8rOrLrByRN21kUrDCH4yhCr8na7C/Xo0fdwnZXbrGnZB7gwTF7lUsHXBGzzHBOibHeo9Qeb924naaHsMe0uKXkLqghSoZVVdvhnv2Rj/Gc0rwpnrAkcjMm2Y5lIM@sY8mDnWIlh@zNmGOZ4FbxHA96M4jlM3TeMUDlq43g/8rH2SxP7q/gA)

`m:g/<:L>+/` returns an array of match objects, one for each sequence of letters in the input.  `».lc` calls the `lc` (lowercase) method on each of those match objects, coercing them to strings in the process.  `sort` and `unique` are self-explanatory, hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 93 bytes

```
func[s][a: charset[#"a"-#"z"]sort unique parse lowercase s[collect[any[keep some a | skip]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9bS8NAEIXf@yuOWyhtMSD1oaagYJ4UFMQnYQky2UzI0mR33d3QKP73urFehnmYy8eZOZ7r4zPXspw1OxybwSgZSkk7qJZ84CjngkQ2Fx@iDNZHDEa/DQw3LdHZA3tFqQpS2a5jFSWZd7lndgi2ZxA@EfbalSmOjfVMqkVgE9kohpwhhYitDkhJBvxCj@6BYZupuzduiOIE3bHnE2Rjyx48Uu@6X1JP5Dm@laJOhw86tnhKduJAUVtz9iOzyS@Wi21@dbmhW1quF1hvc2TZdVEU1aqqigpLjFita2RqTMirmJUSzmsTIZOB/v97kd0I9Lar0fwNk8sv)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `MList::Util=uniq -F'[^a-zA-Z]+'`, 27 bytes

```perl
say for uniq sort map{lc}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY27CsJAEAB/Za1S6Eks0gQEbYKFgo2NonCEDVm4l3d7@MJfd71UA8PABIymEUn6BYOPkB3dIfnIYHX4mP676UR2GBEogXaeR4yAT22DQfBDUUAuZF4Aj6VgsggP4hGO2fWcNZN3s58PE5OoQ7OsV3XhnhK37YnJrKelqK663LR6b9X5Oq/@)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

05AB1E has a built-in that I don't even know!

```
l.γa}ʒa}ê
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/R@/c5sTaU5MSaw@v@v/fI7UoVSGzWCExL78kI7VIIbUiMbcgJ1UhPw0opJCZV1BaoqNQkgFUUZKZm6pQnlmSoRBQmpdcUppYkpmfp6gIAA)

### Explanation

```
l         Lowercase
 .γ       Group by:
   a}     Is alphabetic?
     ʒa}  Filter: is alphabetic?
        ê sorted uniquify
```

Answer (score 2):

## PostgreSQL, 80 bytes

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(lower($1),'[^a-z]')UNION SELECT''ORDER BY 1OFFSET 1
```

Input is given as a query parameter and output is given as one word per row. Changing `lower` to `upper` outputs in uppercase instead. `initcap` also works but is 2 more bytes.

### Explanation

`regexp_split_to_table` splits a string based on the regular expression provided.
`UNION SELECT''` is used to add the empty string and also remove duplicates.
`ORDER BY 1` is used to sort the results
`OFFSET 1` is used to not output the empty string.

If the empty string is sometimes allowed, the following 67 byte solution works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT regexp_split_to_table(lower($1),'[^a-z]')ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s><sup>13</sup></s> 12 bytes

```
↓¬uO†_mf√ġK√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1Hb5ENrSv0fNSyIz0171DHryEJvIPn//38jSwMNNXNLC2OjRMdEDS01BS1zSwVdXVsnJ6ckzaQkpyQFDYUKBU2tFAXd5AqgkngA)

-1 byte from Jo King.

### Explanation

```
↓¬uO†_mf√ġK√
         ġK√ Group the input on non alphabet chars
      mf√    filter out non-alphabet chars.
    †_       convert all characters to lowercase
   O         sort in ascending order
  u          uniquify
↓¬           drop all empty strings at the beginning
```

Comment: @Jo King ah, it works since they're ordered. Nice find.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 16 bytes

```
zz"[a-z]+"~?NB><
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/qkopOlG3KlZbqc7ez8nO5v9/I0sDDTVzSwtjo0THRA0tNQUtc0sFXV1bJyenJM2kJKckBQ2FCgVNrRQF3eQKoJJ4AA)

Explanation:

```
zz               # Lowercase input
  "[a-z]+"~?     # Get list of all regex matches
            NB   # Remove duplicates
              >< # Sort
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 8 bytes

*5 bytes removed thanks to [@Sanchises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises)!*

```
k3Y4XXuS
```

Output is in lowercase.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9s40iQiojT4/391I0sDDTVzSwtjo0THRA0tNQUtc0sFXV1bJyenJM2kJKckBQ2FCgVNrRQF3eQKoJJ4dQA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NcxBC4IwGMbxe5/i7eJUGoQG5qFDo0NBQVCHdap3tnCkU@wd@e2XFsFzeeDHv0aq/M0/08tCSnfyjHMmN2fPqDQvGIYWtMRDu9fQPMa3s60jNmFb3ekfaKjUHege67b6KzOqGXwrZGoNb0MlHJ0tyCGZxk6HRJLPwyDLl2mCawzjAOIsB85XQggVKSUUhNBDFN@BF/1AruwD).

#### How it works

```
k          % Implicit input: string. Convert to lowercase
3Y4        % Push string '[A-Za-z]+' (predefined literal)
XX         % Regexp match. Gives a cell array of substrings
u          % Unique
S          % Sort. Implicit display
```

Comment: Why not `k3Y4XXuS`?

Comment: @Sanchises Thank you! I had completely forgotten about the `Y4` literals

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
Ｆ⪫  ↧Ｓ¿№βι⊞§υ±¹ι⊞υ⟦⟧≔⟦⟧ζＷ⁻υζ⊞ζ⌊ι✂Ｅζ⪫ιω¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv/oolh7AyMrTpITUmB7unlKYEcgyhSIpiLzhSsKTa@OdVuaV7m3nDzqhODMqKPsabHQDfLRlcAaw4fNhRD0o4jXvzCP7kBzItsnRAN8A3G4xHyYGScQyuw9rvzVVPGDh86lZ4jc@MLbwC3Tv9F0rwfGFVVjtHrcHzhcOc5NhRrwEPZIJbMvP/05lDMuke7piKquyYVng89aQ0HsRj4b@bicO4tKXKKsZN@YTrbfn6shG1wHwN@baEotg1TSOZlI0EhAlYfoVCTSnylcXiu/8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⪫  ↧Ｓ
```

Wrap the lowercased input in spaces and loop over the characters.

```
¿№βι
```

If this is a letter, ...

```
⊞§υ±¹ι
```

... then append it to the last entry, ...

```
⊞υ⟦⟧
```

... otherwise start a new entry.

```
≔⟦⟧ζ
```

Start a list of unique entries.

```
Ｗ⁻υζ
```

While there are more entries, ...

```
⊞ζ⌊ι
```

... add the lexicographically first entry to the list of unique entries. This also ends up sorting the deduplicated list.

```
✂Ｅζ⪫ιω¹
```

Join the entries back into strings and print all but the first (which is always empty).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

<sup>13 bytes if we may include the empty word as a leading entry - exclude the trailing `Ḋ` (maybe?).

11 bytes if we may output an empty word, but not always - exclude `⁸Ż` also (probably not).</sup>

```
e€ØẠa⁸Żṣ0ŒlQṢḊ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/9qZWxsef//ZeKCrMOY4bqgYeG5ozDFkmxR4bmi4biK/8OHS///IjI5MCgmNzk4MzJhQWEoKiYgKjc5IC0tPUJCQmIpYmJCYiAoIHggKSpkIC1jeGFBYV8i)**

#### How?

```
e€ØẠa⁸Żṣ0ŒlQṢḊ - Link: list of charachters, S       e.g. "I((or))a"
  ØẠ           - Latin alphabet characters               "AB...Zab...z"
e€             - for each (c in S): exists in (ØẠ)?      [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
    a⁸         - logical AND (vectorises) (with chain's left argument = S)       ['i',0,0,'o','r',0,0,'a']
      Ż        - prepend a zero (for S like "abc")       [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1] 
       ṣ0      - split at zeros                          [[],['I'],[],['o','r'],[],['a']]
         Œl    - lower-case                              [[],['i'],[],['o','r'],[],['a']]
           Q   - deduplicate                             [[],['i'],['o','r'],['a']]
            Ṣ  - sort                                    [[],['a'],['i'],['o','r']]
             Ḋ - dequeue (remove the empty word)         [['a'],['i'],['o','r']]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 44 bytes

Drops the potential empty word, otherwise -4 bytes.

```
}.@~.@/:~@([;._2~2|1+'@Z'&I.)@toupper@,&'  '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczBasJAGATge59i2kP@3TRZbXqwiQjbFETBQulJ7EE2dkO21GRJNzQHzavHqAgzh4GP@ekfBOWYJSAEGCMZGgq8fa7m/VHITshR0kn2NRXbqIsOT48kN@QtBZeuaqzVtQw8AqjnPZvmHOQK84chqoReq3e70qjy81qWtnF0d1ULXeurqlyha@hW7e3vjZozDXC5cmav8W9cgY@m3LlGOVOV97efKB4zbxK/PEfqVTHfgz@JEYazNE0znmVpBoYW3P9GuGsHsqUT)

#### How it works

```
}.@~.@/:~@([;._2~2|1+'@Z'&I.)@toupper@,&'  '
                                      ,&'  ' append two spaces
                              toupper        one of the few functions, non
                                              J user can guess by name :)
          (          '@Z'&I.)                index into intervals …@](A…Z](_…
                 2|1+                        add 0 and mod 2, so A-Z is 0, else 1
           [;._2~                            partition the string into groups,
                                              each group ends with 1 (exclusive).
                                              the end is based on the last item,
                                              which is space -> 1   
      /:~                                    sort the strings
   ~.                                        remove duplicates
}.                                           remove head,
                                              which will be the space group
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://cran.r-project.org/), 60 bytes

```r
sort(setdiff(strsplit(tolower(readline()),"[^a-z]")[[1]],"")
```

Used `setdiff` to remove possible empty strings, but it deduplicates as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 88 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
import Data.List
s=sort.nub.words.map f
f x|isAlpha x=toLower x
f _=' '
```

Replace non-alpha characters with spaces so we can use `words` to split it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJRb5swEMff@RQ3q2ohBVZ1D12kUinpHjYpkSb1YZO6qjLBFGvGRvYxeNh3zw4MJJtmgc@@O//ur7Mr7n4KpY6yboxFeDQarVHp3mheQFhKhcLuY@gqoaM56RNHnj5W3Abnjp10GLjMkSPVbZ52xhYurXkDZVBC/1u6jWoqDn2GZmc6YaEn/2t2BVfHmksNGRQmAFACQfSNOKAoHDmfyTePkGElHdDHNYjvfN/sBJhy2H3RTYsshmfGNYuZ6HndKEEr6QNMOppMSdPAYC/Rwo2J@1lY4bkGK9I2nZ/gIyOGsTjKWkAnsYKvrT5gy1Ea/e5UeSL8pYH2/5fSnBCzMDJUgcxQ41@Zt@ub8PJu/fHDLd/wcHUJq7s1JEm23W7zKM@3OYTQQ7QqIDn0lPLqdXFOvJwGGfKP24L@/pz/Ekzdd0b9EtR5R/vOGv0G9wmUStJN@vdwdj8X8COcumNaJBtB8uAv0sOscK3CgTZSx9wlKN23kZ/Nae@zCTOmDK9uybmYhFLwCe1OU2nmmQyurz14WDDouPM@V5luJo@RnFLI2aoCKk4nc0EFTqlnpa3A1i7Fh86MYkLdKuWbEk2KFj1sQ6E3Y4qUHf8A)

Comment: If you remove the Data.Char import, ``f x|x>'`',x<'{'=x|x>'@',x<'['=[x..]!!32;f _=' '`` saves a single byte :).

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 201 bytes

```rust
fn main(){let y=&mut"".into();std::io::stdin().read_line(y);y.retain(|c|c.is_alphabetic()||c==' ');*y=y.to_lowercase();let mut v=y.split(" ").collect::<Vec<_>>();v.sort();v.dedup();println!("{:?}", v)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BbsMgEEWvMmXhgFWjKl2kxiFVfYhuEcZERSLGgrEbK87ZXdzdG82b@T9OCbftOsBNu4Gyh7cIiyxuExLC3YCBsiZhL4QLQmTYJR6t7pV3g6ULa5Y84n68mtVwl5T244/uLDpD2boaKQ9wYE25yIVjUD782mh0svnxHpaTYM6rNHqHlABh3ATvrUEhzt/WnNXlktWZpxDxH3rbT2OmMeZ@fnih5CE@n@QVZvbctmP9RotT/fF@1F@algWUpxqqSrZt27GuazugcAdW9lCZe1bUHw)

```rust
fn main(){
    let y = &mut"".into();std::io::stdin().read_line(y); //Get input into string
    y.retain(|c|c.is_alphabetic()||c==' '); //Retain spaces and letters in string
    *y=y.to_lowercase(); //Convert to lowercase
    let mut v=y.split(" ").collect::<Vec<_>>(); //Split string by space and collect into vector
    v.sort(); //sort Vec
    v.dedup(); //delete duplicates (only works on sorted Vec)
    println!("{:?}", v) //debug-print vector (because no std::fmt::Display for Vec<&str>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 93 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
s=sort.nub.words.map(((do c<-"q69";(" "<*['1'..c])++['a'..'z'])!!).fromEnum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZL/i9MwGMZ/31/xLhy3ZGurd@LO4SbcVFDYQPAHhVokXbNrME1qktohd3/7fPttm2LZmi/vk8/z8KY5dz@EUkdZlMZ6eGu0t0ZFW6N5BnQvlRd2G0CdC80G0TvuebSRzo/cyuFGpKs0qo3NXFTwklKaGdgtQ/JzviCvKQGynMaTm0kU7RI2m8UTjtPJ70nCxmMW7a0p3uuqYMeCSw0ryMwIoLRSe4i7Y8l4THV4w@ARNCzDeP4ymAeLJEGdEh7EoRQ7LzKHh2PcGx5KfC4d4I9rEF/5ttwIMPtm9VGXlScBxIRrEhBx4EWpBM5kVyDS4cvs8dUwSMJO3AC5H4QVHdf4XFjoz/fwlhFAa@5lIaCWPodPld75intp9Pjs3BP@yoDr/0cpz4ghGA7ogEPj8W/M28Vzen23ePXilt9zOr2G6d0CwnC1Xq9TlqbrFCgcgE0zCHcHlHx/6oJxjsAUHxyw0C4z/B8uDZJR335n1C@BrXe4rq3RD3hFsFeyhP7rubigK/hG@/aYyuPIIHzT3XgHs8JVyje0ltpqT0XpvrT81SB7tuoxraT5Rk@aqz4oFj97u9FoTTomgdmsAzcTAjV33Z7LTT2Q20qKEtysVAY5x5OpQIOz9MLaCl/Zk3nTmTYM1ZVSXVNYn@iUh9xj6cGYLCLHPw)

It's not shorter than the other Haskell answer, but I thought this approach was pretty fun.

It creates a big string like `"...               abc...xyz      abc...xyz     ..."` so that indexing into this string performs the same mapping as `f` in the other answer.

I'm including `s=` because the other answer also is.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>59</s> 46 bytes

```clj
#(sort(set(re-seq #"[a-z]+"(.toLowerCase %))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5BS8NAEAXge37Fc4tlEl2Reqg59NB4UajgUQhBNsmErKS7cTOhwT8fE8XhXR58PKbq/OcYeKaaGzTzhgYfhAYWCqwH/sJG5UZ/FzeK7sSf/IXDkxkY1/FycxxR7VeVT8gjJa0dsMQ48Lt57U8M36ztxfWjqEg9c@A/4KXlAJ7Mue/@lV3VLX5XxJ4ZFyst3kZXyWjEene1TOzSe9ru08eHnTkaSrZI9im0PmRZVsZlmZUgTIiTGrqaFvKhoqIA9cE66RyowbR@/gM)

13 bytes saved by NikoNyrh.

Comment: Java-interop to `.toLowerCase` is bit shorter :)

Comment: Indeed, I was so frustrated dealing with the fact that Clojure doesn't expose string functions in the core, that didn't even try thinking about interop :)

Answer (score 0):

## [QuadS](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 15 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
∪⍵[⍋⍵]
\pL+
\l&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn@//9Rx6pHvVujH/V2A6lYrpgCH22umBy1//@NLA001MwtLYyNEh0TNbTUFLTMLRV0dW2dnJySNJOSnJIUNBQqFDS1UhR0kyuASuIB)

`∪` **U**nique elements of
`⍵[`…`]` the data reordered to:
 `⍋⍵` the order that would sort it ascending

where the data is:

`\pL+` all runs of **L**etters

`\l&` mapped to **l**owercase

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 82 bytes

```php
$a=array_filter(array_unique(preg_split("/[^a-z]+/",strtolower($argn))));sort($a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrRCoIwGIbhWxkislnDsIMSk2gH3UTU@JdmA3Pr3yzr4rOB38EHD7z2bqfd3oaPoQJE@Mib7nyDdMbQ6@fQUItNK53ttKdRdroA/54XWbR0Hr3pzDvkMWDbs7DSGfSBrJxegLIeHnZWXqxosim26xwOQNOEpJuCcF4JIRRTSihCyUhYWhN@HUMif8Z6bXo38eMf)

I'm still not satisfied by it, but so far the best I could find.. Yeah array functions names are looooong in PHP :S

The question doesn't ask to display the dictionary, so it's in the footer ;P

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
áмS¡lê
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MILe4IPLcw5vOr/fyNLAw01c0sLY6NEx0QNLTUFLXNLBV1dWycnpyTNpCSnJAUNhQoFTa0UBd3kCqCSeAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TpuSZV1BaYqWgZF@pw6XkX1oC4x2e8P/wwgt7gg8tzDm86r/OoW32/0syMosVgCgxTyE1ItG3wCdVIT8NxAObweWRWpQKkc4vyUgtUkitSMwtyIGpyQSp0VEAm1GSmZuqUJ5ZkqEQUJqXXFKaWJKZn6fIZWRpoKFmbmlhbJTomKihpaagZW6poKtr6@TklKSZlOSUpKChUKGgqZWioJtcAVQSz1WSWlwCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
á       # Only leave letters of the (implicit) input-string
 м      # Remove all those letters from the (implicit) input-string
  S     # Convert the remaining characters to a list of characters
   ¡    # Split the (implicit) input-string on those characters
    l   # Convert everything to lowercase
     ê  # Sort and uniquify the words
```

NOTE: This doesn't work in the new version of 05AB1E for two reasons:

1. The `¡` would also keep empty string items.
2. A single word wouldn't be wrapped into a list, so something like input `"test"` would result in output `"est"` due to the `ê` working directly on this single string instead of a list.

[See the result of all test cases in the new version of 05AB1E.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TpuSZV1BaYqWgZF@pw6XkX1oC4x2e8P/wwgt7gg8tzDm86r/OoW32/0syMosVgCgxTyE1ItG3wCdVIT8NxAObweWRWpQKkc4vyUgtUkitSMwtyIGpyQSp0VEAm1GSmZuqUJ5ZkqEQUJqXXFKaWJKZn6fIZWRpoKFmbmlhbJTomKihpaagZW6poKtr6@TklKSZlOSUpKChUKGgqZWioJtcAVQSz1WSWlwCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) (+"sort" callout), 87 bytes

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ")&&$0=tolower($0){for(;$++a;)!b[$a]++?c=c $a"\n":0;printf c|"sort"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrdCoIwGADQV/kaY2yuwbALU5Fwj5FZfJsZUbiYhtLPs6/O9cH5FuNlfFpOmiOqV632LVkTIIIxqqvJ3/18Dpxq8e594CWVEkuxsg3FVsqdqxxQJIeBFLp8hOsw9eA@ZPRhIt8Y01xzluXbTYo18oRBkuUFIoJSlTHGCmtNZ4HDAiLpQLnl/04/)

This AWK version is longer than the entry Abigail submitted (once it's golfed a bit) but it shows a trick I thought was worth highlighting.

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ")&&$0=tolower($0){ ... }
```

The `gsub` call translates all the non-alphabetic characters to spaces, then the `$0=tolower($0)` bit does two things.  It converts everything to lowercase, then the assignment effectively re-maps the string to positional parameters, dealing with all the added spaces.  As a result if `$1` was `=BBBb)))bbBdb` originally, after running through those calls, the data would set `$1="BBBd"` and `$2="bbDdb"`.

Once the input line has been cleaned up,

```
for(;$++a;)!b[$a]++?c=c $a"\n":0
```

loops through all the words via `$++a`, and for each one increments a frequency counter array for that word `b[$a]++`.  If the value of that frequency counter is 0, the ternary appends the word plus a LF to an accumulator string.

Then the code prints the accumulated string and pipes it to "sort" with this line.

```
printf c|"sort"
```